# How to renew Facebook access token with using Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, access-token, facebook-access-token

I have a simple action for auto posting data on Facebook, it's something like this:

```
pages = FbGraph::User.me(temp_token).accounts
page = pages.detect do |page|
  if page.identifier == my_page
    page.feed!(
      :message => "a title",
      :link => 'a link',
      :description => "a description",
      :picture => 'an image'
    )
  end
  break
end
```

I am thinking how to get new token - I've tried something like this:

```
require 'net/http'
temp_token = 'the current access token'

looky_co_app_id = 'APP_ID'
looky_co_app_secret = 'APP_SECRET'
puts "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=#{looky_co_app_id}&client_secret=#{looky_co_app_secret}&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=#{temp_token}"
url = URI.parse("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=#{looky_co_app_id}&client_secret=#{looky_co_app_secret}&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=#{temp_token}")
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}
puts res.body
```

But I get the error like this:

```
Errno::ECONNRESET in my_controller_name#the_action

Connection reset by peer
```

I am not sure if I am doing it right, but how to correctly renew the access token?